# JPA multi-tier relationship

Tags: database, database-design, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a problem where I am stuck :(. I have to build a relationship of a relationship( strange !).
For example, I have a relation where  one entity A can have many B (OneToMany)

```
A ----> B
```

Now I need another relationship where an entity C will have an OneToOne relationship with the composite relationship between A and B. Like,

```
C--> (A--->B)  , not C-->A-->B
```

Not that C will have a relation with A and A has  with B,it should be like like C--> D (A --> B).

The generated joined tables does not have any primary key in JPA and now I am thinking How can I map this relationship. Please be noted that the normal A-->B is also needed as this can not be embeddable and it should be persistent.

Thanks.

Example:
Location and Event are my two entities and I want  to relate CleanPlan on it. Means one CleanPlan is related to event-1 of location-1. so I am specifying that have a cleanplan on location-1 in event-1. Does that make sense?

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a real-life example? Describe actual entities.

Comment: For example, Location and Event are my two entities and I want  to relate CleanPlan on it. Means one CleanPlan is related to event-1 of location-1. so I am specifying that have a cleanplan on location-1 in event-1. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this

[image]

or this, depending on Event-Location cardinality.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot ,yes,but how to do this in JPA ? Should I make a class named EventLocation? if yes,then If I have 10 entities and want to make this relation between them,there would be too many classes

Comment: @Shahriar, did you mean too many objects? This is like an **association class**.

Comment: no,think in terms of JPA entity, In my Event entity I relate @OneToMany with Location, so the lookup table eventlocation is created,but I dont use it as a Java Entity class.Now If I want to relate CleanPlan entity with this lookup table,in which part and how should I declare my association.Do I need to write that EventLocation class and then in CleanPlan entity class I write @OnetoOne EvenLocation ? like that?

Comment: I would create a separate class, because you do need an **association class** -- as opposed to just using default mappings.

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects of this problem in JPA.
1) A mapping table is craeted.
2) A mapping row is created instead of mapping table.

I think the 2nd option will make your life easier. But that is only possible if Event and Location has an unidirectional relation. Then on ManyToOne side, put "mappedBy". And that will generate a mapping table on ManyToOne table. And you can refer that column on CleanPlan table.